# jQuery animate return callback value

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-callback

I'm pretty sure that the answer to this question is floating around somewhere, but I have no idea on which keywords to search...

Got this:

```
...
var currLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollLeft: currLeft+width+'px'
}, 1200, function(){
    currLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
});
...
```

After the animation is done, I would like to replace the currLeft from the function() with the 'first' currLeft...

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for all the answers, but the directions you point me in is not what I'm looking for :-)
Let's say you've got this:

```
var currLeft = 'Whats your name?';
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollLeft: currLeft+width+'px'
}, 1200, function(){
    currLeft = 'Its Hank'
});
```

I want to replace the 'Whats your name?' with 'Its Hank' in this situation, the first currLeft remains: 'Whats your name?'

Comment: Do you mean something like `var currLeft = $(window).scrollLeft() + width;` in your first line?

Comment: No, the things is that I need to replace the content of the currLeft var. (let's say it's 100 before the animation, during the animation it increases, and I need the value after it's done...)

Comment: @Yoshi ow, sorry! I always place a +1... didn't know this...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but might be this way:

```
var currLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollLeft: currLeft+width+'px'
}, 1200, function(){
    $('html, body').scrollLeft(currLeft);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the things is that I need to replace the content of the currLeft var. (let's say it's 100 before the animation, during the animation it increases, and I need the value after it's done...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var currLeft = $(window).scrollLeft(),
    currLeft2 = "";
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollLeft: currLeft+width+'px'
}, 1200, function(){
  currLeft2 = 'Its hank';
});
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for, I've updated my question, maybe it's more clear now...

Comment: Updated. It seems like you're looking for a second variable entirely.